# How to support C++20 modules on CLion for Mac

Tags: c++, macos, clang, c++20, clion

I can't use the Clion 2023.3 to compile cpp20 modules code successfully.
Here is the code:

```
//Hello.cppm
#include <iostream>
export module Hello;
export void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

```
//main.cpp
import Hello;
int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

when I build these code, some errors come out:

```
error: module interface compilation requires '-std=c++20' or '-fmodules-ts'
error: unknown type name 'import'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'hello'
```

I searched on some site and decide to build it in Clion's terminal
First build the module:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts Hello.cppm --precompile -o Hello.pcm
```

Hello.pcm was generated with no error,
then build the main.cpp:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -fmodule-file=Hello=Hello.pcm Hello.pcm -o Hello.out
```

errors comes again:

```
error: unknown type name 'import'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'hello'
```

my os version is macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, clang version 15
clion toolchains used Bundled(cmake 3.27.8)

Anybody can help?
Thx!

Comment: clang on macOS is apple clang, which does not support modules AFAIK.  you generally need to use homebrew to get gcc or clang.

Comment: Use either `-std=c++20` or `-fmodules-ts`, but don't use both. The modules TS has been superseded by C++20, so I recommend the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as compiler switches go, use either `-std=c++20` or `-fmodules-ts`, but do not use both. The modules TS has been superseded by C++20, so I recommend the former.

The only mistake I saw in the program itself was to omit the *global module fragment*. That comes first in a module unit, and begins with the `module;` declaration.

Old-school include directives belong in the global module fragment.

```cpp
// hello.cppm
// Clang uses the file extension `.cppm` for "module interface units."

module;               // "global module fragment" begins here
// Include directives belong in the global module fragment.
#include <iostream>

// The global module fragment ends when a module declaration is encountered.
export module Hello;  

export void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
// end file: hello.cppm
```

According to the [Clang documentation for modules](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html#file-name-requirement):

> The file name of an importable module unit should end with .cppm (or .ccm, .cxxm, .c++m). The file name of a module implementation unit should end with .cpp (or .cc, .cxx, .c++).
>
> If the file names use different extensions, Clang may fail to build the module.

So, make sure the file name of your *module interface unit* ends with `.cppm`.

Non-module files, such as `main.cpp` are regular C++ translation units. So, they should use the file name extension `.cpp`.

Your file `main.cpp` looks fine.

```cpp
// main.cpp
import Hello;
int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

I am not a Clang user, so I ran your program under MSVC. Might be irrelevant as far as Clang is concerned, but the program above ran correctly in Visual Studio (although I did use Microsoft's `ixx` file name extension for the module interface unit).

Note: the program above is very similar to [one given in the Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html#id14). For that program, the docs recommend the following compilation commands:

> $ clang++ -std=c++20 Hello.cppm --precompile -o Hello.pcm
>
> $ clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -fmodule-file=Hello=Hello.pcm Hello.pcm -o Hello.out
>
> $ ./Hello.out
>
> Hello World!

These are identical to what you are using, except `-fmodules-ts` has been omitted.

##### Modules all the way

You might also try a "modules-only" approach. This places function `main` into a module, and also uses *header units*, rather than include files, for access to the Standard Library. Downstream, you may be able to switch to C++23's `import std;` (which I have been using in Microsoft projects for six months now).

```cpp
// Hello.cppm
export module Hello;  
import <iostream>;   // "header unit"

export void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
// end file: Hello.cppm
```

```cpp
// main.cppm
export module main;
import Hello;

export int main()
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cppm
```

Check the [Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html#id45) for more information about how to compile header units.

Comment: thx dude, I used your advice above, but it didn't work. I ran these code in Visual Studio on windows, it works fine too. so maybe MSVC is more powerful than clang :-p    but thx anyway.

Comment: oh yes, I use the command line in terminal can run these code!! but clion still don't work. maybe my cmakefile has some problem, anyway, I can run in terminal, it's a huge progress!thank you so much.

Comment: Great! I heard Clang was not as far along with modules as Microsoft, but not being able to identify `import` as a keyword indicates a larger problem than that. You're probably right to focus on the CLion and Cmake configuration files. BTW, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) the latest stable Clang release is version 17. I don't know if upgrading is a possibility for you, but it might be worth checking into.

Comment: char_fan - could you recap what commands you did. I am having problem as well with this and not sure which input you used of the above several given nor the 2 command lines to build it in MacOS terminal. 

Way appreciate it if you can let us know!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145179/macos-intel-xcode-version-15-2-and-c20-modules-new-to-this-and-cannot-get